# Escaping single quote ' in sql parameterized query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert data using sql query in vb.net as follows. name = corp int'l poc = 1

When I tried to insert, I get an error ("Unclosed Quotation Mark after the character String '"). This happens when I tried to insert name with only 1 single quote.

Therefore I added a replace function to replace 1 single quote with 2 single quote to escape the symbol. There was no error but when I look into my database, 2 single quotes are added instead of 1.

Can anyone advise me how I can escape the single quote with my parameterized query? Thanks!

```
 Public Function InsertData(ds As DataSet) As Boolean
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    Dim status As Boolean
    Dim name As String
    Dim poc As String

    Dim id_p As New SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    Dim name_p As New SqlParameter("name", SqlDbType.VarChar)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(id_p)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(name_p)

    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        If checkExists(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString(), ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString(), ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(3).ToString()) = True Then


            name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            poc = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString()

            If name.Contains("'") Then
                name = name.Replace("'", "''")
            End If
            If poc.Contains("'") Then
                poc = poc.Replace("'", "'")
            End If

            name_p.SqlValue = name
            id_p.SqlValue = poc


            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Code (Name,ID)" _
                              & " VALUES (@name,@id)"

            status = ExecuteNonQuerybySQLCommand(cmd)
        End If
    Next

    Return status

End Function


Dim strcon As String = "Data Source=x.x.x.x,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=code_DB;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"

 Public Function ExecuteNonQuerybySQLCommand(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    sqlcon.ConnectionString = strcon
    cmd.Connection = sqlcon

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlcon.Close()

        If i > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(ex)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the single quotes when they are in parameters.

Comment: ...and it seems unlikely the error comes from that code.  If the data is in a DataTable, it seems odd to pull it out to use it in a query

Comment: The problem appears to be in your `ExecuteNonQuerybySQLCommand` function, which you have not shown to us.

Comment: Apologies. updated with my execute query & connection string. masked off the sensitive information though. I understand that sqlparameters do not require to be escaped. But I was not able to comprehend what is wrong with my query.

Comment: There was an additional single quote in my query in checkexists function. Therefore it caused the error in my insert query. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values passed as parameters (i.e. SqlParameter object) do not need to be escaped.  This is because the client API uses an RPC call to execute the query, with the query itself and parameters passed separately.  With an RPC call, the actual parameter values are sent to SQL Server in native (binary) format over the TDS protocol rather than embedded within the statement.  This mitigates SQL injection concerns and provides other benefits, such as strong-typing and improved performance.